# Getting the time remaining before event.wait is done in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, timeout

I'm writing a Python script in which i have a thread running that calculates some values and creates a graph every hour. What I would like to do is have a function in that thread that tells me how much time there is remaining before the next update happens. My current implementation is as follows:

```
class StatsUpdater(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, updateTime):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.updateTime = updateTime

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.is_set():
            self.updateStats()
            self.event.wait(self.updateTime)

    def updateStats(self):
        print "Updating Stats"
        tables = SQLInterface.listTables()

        for table in tables:
            PlotTools.createAndSave(table)

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()
```

So what i would like is adding another function in that class that gives me back the time remaining gefore self.event.wait(self.updateTime) times out, something like this:

```
def getTimeout(self):
    return self.event.timeRemaining()
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i have a compromis to my problem. I implemented a variable in StatsUpdater.run:

```
self.lastUpdateTime = int(time.time())
```

right before i do the update function.

Now when I call getTimeout(), I do:

```
def getTimeout(self):
    timePassed = int(time.time() - self.lastUpdateTime
    return self.updateTime - timePassed
```

This way, I don't have a calculation intensive thread running and calculation
a small sum every second but i still get a pretty good indication of when the next update is since the ammount of time between updates is also known ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i got the idea while reading your reply ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for getting the remaining time directly but you can sleep several times and keep track of how much time remains.

```
def __init__(self, updateTime):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.event = threading.Event()
    self.updateTime = updateTime
    self.wait_time=None

def run(self):
    while not self.event.is_set():
        self.updateStats()
        try:
            self.wait_time=self.updateTime
            inttime=int(self.updateTime)
            remaining=inttime-self.updateTime
            self.event.wait(remaining)
            for t in reversed(range(inttime)): 
                self.wait_time=t+1
                self.event.wait(1)
        finally:
            self.wait_time=0
```

And then use

```
def getTimeout(self):
    return self.wait_time
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that myself aswell, thanks for the feedback though. The problem is that this program is running on the Raspberry Pi (dunno if you heard of it) so i have verry little resources and i'm worried having to do wait_time=t+1 every second will just consume to much time/resources on the system. Is there any other way i can implement this? If not, id rather keep it as it is now, being able to read the time untill the next update is more of a luxury then a must.

Comment: Just try it. Perhaps it's to slow but I doubt you will notice. You could also change the sleep time to say 5 seconds.